# Need help on AutoCompleteTextView for Searching

Tags: android

I have implemented an `AutoCompleteTextView` for searching. Is `AutoCompleteTextView` supported in all SDK versions and targets, because when I tried this [sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html)
it shows an empty dropdown list. When I used the same in my application for parsed content placed inside a string array, I'm getting an Exception.

```
Log.v("Length of a",Integer.toString(a.length));
try{
    wv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    place_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.v("Length of a222222",Integer.toString(a.length));

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bru_Maps.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, a);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
} catch(Exception e) {                  
    Log.v("Error","search_name"+e);     
}
```

The above given code prints the log well but it returns a `NullPointerException`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bru_Maps.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, a);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I can see from the example, you need to set the Threshold value to 1, if you want to see the list of available countries after you type the first character in the TextView. Use `autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1)` to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comments yet, so... What is the datatype for **a**? You wrote that it is a *string* when it needs to be an *array of strings*.